# "The name "DisplayAlert" does not exist in current context." Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I'm trying to make an alert in Xamarin using this code:

```
    private async void AboutMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
    }
```

But VS showed this error :

```
    The name "DisplayAlert" does not exist in current context.
```

I searched Internet for solution and i found this:

```
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert ("Hello", "No");
```

And:

```
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert ("Hello", "No");
```

I tried these new codes and they show another error:

```
    Application does not contain a definition for "Current"    ....
```

Comment: is `AboutMe_Click` contained within a `Page` class?  Is your project a Xamarin Forms project?

Comment: @Jason My project is a a Xamarin Forms project and I think there is no Page class.

Comment: what is the class that you are trying to execute `DisplayAlert` in?  `DisplayAlert` is a method on `Page` so only works on classes that inherit from a `Page` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin.forms, if you used this code in the code behind of a Page Click event, you could try the code below.

```
 public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
    }
}
```

And use the code below works as the same as the previous code when you do not use it in Page. Use the `App` instead of `Application`

```
 await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
```

Output:

[image]